# Can't Find Generate Code. UML Class Diagram To code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, uml

I am trying to Convert Uml Class Diagram into Code
I am using this [msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff657795.aspx) as help but this is for VS 2012 so it cant help a lot.

I have made two projects

1. UML class diagram from Modelling
2. C# Console  Application

and I have added Reference of C# Console Application in UML class Diagram .

I have already made uml class Diagram in Modeling project but can not go further because i don't find any option like Generate code etc
I have also made class diagram file in Console project of extension .cd but i cant put relationship between classes .just add new classes .interface etc 
Kindly help me to understand me this concept and send me more related links.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have the "Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Visualization and Modeling Feature Pack" installed in order to be able to generate the code from the class diagrams. Here's the link explaining how to do it in using Visual Studio 2010:

[How to: Generate Code from UML Class Diagrams in VS2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff636699%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

I haven't tried it myself, but I hope that helps. Good Luck. Stephan

Comment: @alexw: What do you mean with OP? Sorry, I don't get it :). The Ultimate version of VS2012 has already the built in functionality of generating code from a UML class diagram as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff657795.aspx).